# How to resolve mypy errors when changing values with a Literal type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I need to change the value of an attribute that has a `Literal` type.
In a real case, I have a long list of values in ValidChar and I need to convert it to `List[str]` for checking.
`mypy` shows an error for the following example. How can I solve it?

```py
from typing import Literal

ValidChar = Literal["A", "B"]


class MyClass:
    char: ValidChar = "A"

    def set_char(self, char: str) -> None:
        """Set only valid character."""
        if char in ValidChar.__args__:
            self.char = char


obj = MyClass()
print(f"{obj.char=}")  # obj.char='A'

# char is valid
obj.set_char("B")
print(f"{obj.char=}")  # obj.char='B'

# char is invalid
obj.set_char("C")
print(f"{obj.char=}")  # obj.char='B'
```

mypy error:

I trying to solve `expression has type "str", variable has type "Literal['A', 'B']"`

```
$ mypy .
2.py:11: error: "<typing special form>" has no attribute "__args__"  [attr-defined]
2.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "Literal['A', 'B']")  [assignment]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 3 source files)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just resolve your errors, you can do the following ([`get_args` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args)):

```py
from typing import Literal, cast, get_args

ValidChar = Literal["A", "B"]


class MyClass:
    char: ValidChar = "A"

    def set_char(self, char: str) -> None:
        """Set only valid character."""
        if char in get_args(ValidChar):
            # OK to cast - validated above.
            # mypy does not infer literals from strings this way.
            self.char = cast(ValidChar, char)
```

This [passes](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=1349b509fc212589328ddd06cbbfa092) type checking. To get rid of `cast`, you can extract a helper function or method ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=553f6a58698c8712f5c17589b9650a19)):

```py
from typing import Literal, TypeGuard, get_args

ValidChar = Literal["A", "B"]

def is_valid_char(char: str) -> TypeGuard[ValidChar]:
    return char in get_args(ValidChar)


class MyClass:
    char: ValidChar = "A"

    def set_char(self, char: str) -> None:
        """Set only valid character."""
        if is_valid_char(char):
            self.char = char
```

Finally, from the design perspective I'd rather raise a custom exception on invalid char instead of silently dropping it, such omission may cause hard-to-catch bugs.

Answer (score -3):

Here you can use the Type function to access the underlying type of Literal and then convert it to a list.
Corrected code below.

```
from typing import Literal, Type

ValidChar = Literal["A", "B"]


class MyClass:
    char: ValidChar = "A"

    def set_char(self, char: str) -> None:
        """Set only valid character."""
        if char in Type[ValidChar].__args__:
            self.char = char


obj = MyClass()
print(f"{obj.char=}")  # obj.char='A'

# char is valid
obj.set_char("B")
print(f"{obj.char=}")  # obj.char='B'

# char is invalid
obj.set_char("C")
print(f"{obj.char=}")  # obj.char='B'
```